# Can't access some websites unsing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, internet

I'm using Ubuntu 16.14 , yesterday I can't access some websites using any browsers but in the night all websites became accessible but today until now they are not accessible. I can not understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure these websites you are talking about are up. Check this  [here](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/).
Second, if these websites are indeed online, try to ping them. Open a terminal and type `ping www.website.com`.
If you get a reply, clear your browser's cache and try again. 
If you don't (but you have Internet connectivity in general), then check your DNS settings or contact your ISP.